# meteor.js How to choose prohibit retroactive date in the package “tsega:bootstrap3-datetimepicker”

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a question about the package "tsega:bootstrap3-datetimepicker".

In the template I have placed code:

```
                    <div class="nowe-wydarzenie form-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="nowe-wydarzenie-start-date">Data</label>
                   <div class="input-group datetimepicker">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nowe-wydarzenie-start-date" data-id="nowe-wydarzenie-start-date" name="noweWydarzenieStartDate" placeholder="Podaj datę rozpoczecia wydarzenia" autocapitalize="none" autocorrect="off" value="">
                    </div>
                    <span class="help-block hide"></span>
                </div>
```

and the js file I added the following code:

```
Template.newWydarzenie.onRendered(function() {
    this.$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    });
});
```

With these settings, I have the opportunity to choose the date of bark already passed (01.01.2016)

I would like to block such a choice.

How to set the this package so that it was not possible to select reverse date.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about what you want, an example, and perhaps a code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `minDate` option. This line:

```
this.$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({ minDate: 'now' });
```

allow only future dates.

Comment: It is good to accept an answer - if someone will have the same question - he will know, that this is solution.